# How to Resolve IOS App Crash just in Diawi App

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, diawi

I had tableview with two cells the cells are UIcollectionview , every think work fine in Xcode ,
just when I get the download link from Diawi app and and test it there the app crash in home page

(tableview with collection cell)

my Homepage Code is :

```
 class HomeVC: BaseVC ,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,ContinueLearningDelegate,HeaderViewLearnDelegate{

        @IBOutlet weak var tableView:UITableView!
        @IBOutlet weak var headerView:HeaderViewLearn!
        @IBOutlet weak var headerHeightConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint!

        private var homeStoriesViewModel:HomeStoriesViewModel?

        var shouldAnimate = true
        var selectedLevel = CLoginManager.shared.user?.level
        var fetchDataInViewDidAppear = false

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            registerCells()
            fetchData()
        }

        fileprivate func registerCells(){
            tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 100, right: 0)
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CoursesDescTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CoursesDescTableViewCell.identifier)
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "CoursesDataTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: CoursesDataTableViewCell.identifier)
            tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ContinueLearningTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: ContinueLearningTableViewCell.identifier)
            tableView.dataSource = self
            tableView.delegate = self
            tableView.reloadData()
            headerView.delegateSearchar = self


        }

      func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            if indexPath.section == 0 {
                if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ContinueLearningTableViewCell.identifier,   for: indexPath) as? ContinueLearningTableViewCell {
                    cell.delegate = self
                    cell.configure(stories:(self.homeStoriesViewModel?.getStoriesBy(indexPath.section)) ?? [])
                    return cell
                }
            }
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: CoursesDescTableViewCell.identifier,   for: indexPath) as! CoursesDescTableViewCell
            cell.delegate = self
            cell.fromHome = true
            return cell

        }

    // TableViewCell (homePage)
    class ContinueLearningTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDelegate ,UICollectionViewDataSource{

        static var identifier = "ContinueLearningTableViewCellIdentifier"

        @IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!

        weak var delegate:ContinueLearningDelegate?

        var stories:[Story]?

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            registerCells()
            setupCollectionLayout()
            self.selectionStyle = .none
        }

       private func registerCells() {
            collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CourseProfileCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CourseProfileCollectionViewCell.identifier)

        }

        private func setupCollectionLayout(){

             let flowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
             let height = 320
             flowLayout.itemSize = CGSize(width: (height), height: (height))
             flowLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
             flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 20
             collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout

             collectionView.delegate = self
             collectionView.dataSource = self
         }

        func configure(stories:[Story]){
            self.stories = stories
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }

         func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return stories?.count ?? 0
        }

         func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CourseProfileCollectionViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as!  CourseProfileCollectionViewCell
            if stories != nil {
                cell.configure(story: stories![indexPath.item])
            }
            return cell
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as? CourseProfileCollectionViewCell{
                delegate?.onClickLessonStory(cell: cell,story:self.stories?[indexPath.item])
            }
        }
        override func prepareForReuse() {
            super.prepareForReuse()
        }
    }

the Log print :-

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1b61a896c __exceptionPreprocess + 224
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b5ec1028 objc_exception_throw + 59
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1b60a6dcc -[NSObject+ 200140 (NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 143
3   UIKitCore                       0x1ba2d8884 -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 303
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1b61ad048 ___forwarding___ + 1327
5   CoreFoundation                  0x1b61af3a0 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 95
6   ChaLearn                        0x10494cb20 _hidden#1889_ + 527136 (__hidden#9146_:74)
7   ChaLearn                        0x10494aec4 _hidden#8966_ + 519876 (__hidden#9004_:60)
8   ChaLearn                        0x10494af9c _hidden#8967_ + 520092 (__hidden#419_:0)
9   UIKitCore                       0x1b9adad00 -[UICollectionView _createPreparedCellForItemAtIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:isFocused:notify:] + 443
10  UIKitCore                       0x1b9adf6e8 -[UICollectionView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 4475
11  UIKitCore                       0x1b9ae4244 -[UICollectionView layoutSubviews] + 323
12  UIKitCore                       0x1ba75c8b0 -[UIView+ 15689904 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2155
13  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b5ebca4c -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 67
14  QuartzCore                      0x1bcd7255c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 291
15  QuartzCore                      0x1bcd729ac CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1403308 (CA::Transaction*) + 483
16  UIKitCore                       0x1ba748210 -[UIView+ 15606288 (Hierarchy) layoutBelowIfNeeded] + 551
17  UIKitCore                       0x1ba74ed54 +[UIView+ 15633748 (Animation) performWithoutAnimation:] + 103
18  UIKitCore                       0x1ba4997b0 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:willDisplay:] + 1123
19  UIKitCore                       0x1ba466088 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2591
20  UIKitCore                       0x1ba483838 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 163
21  UIKitCore                       0x1ba75c8b0 -[UIView+ 15689904 (CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2155
22  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1b5ebca4c -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 67
23  QuartzCore                      0x1bcd7255c -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 291
24  QuartzCore                      0x1bcd729ac CA::Layer::layout_if_needed+ 1403308 (CA::Transaction*) + 483
25  QuartzCore                      0x1bcd851bc CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed+ 1479100 (CA::Transaction*) + 139
26  QuartzCore                      0x1bccc9b00 CA::Context::commit_transaction+ 711424 (CA::Transaction*, double) + 307
27  QuartzCore                      0x1bccf4910 CA::Transaction::commit+ 887056 () + 683
28  QuartzCore                      0x1bccf54e4 CA::Transaction::observer_callback+ 890084 (__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 95
29  CoreFoundation                  0x1b6123524 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 35
30  CoreFoundation                  0x1b611e1c4 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 419
31  CoreFoundation                  0x1b611e774 __CFRunLoopRun + 1291
32  CoreFoundation                  0x1b611df40 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 479
33  GraphicsServices                0x1c03ae534 GSEventRunModal + 107
34  UIKitCore                       0x1ba2a9580 UIApplicationMain + 1939
35  ChaLearn                        0x1048d23d0 main + 25552 (__hidden#417_:24)
36  libdyld.dylib                   0x1b5f9ce18 start + 3
```

I had tableview with two cells the cells are UIcollectionview , every think work fine in Xcode ,
just when I get the download link from Diawi app and and test it there the app crash in home page

(tableview with collection cell)

my Homepage Code is :

here is my code and log errors any help please ?

Comment: As per my experience, It seems like OS specific issue there is nothing related to Diawi or anythings else. Do you try to debug in same device?

Comment: What happens if you install a release build on an iPhone locally, instead of using Diawi?